# Is it a bad idea to automatically create database entries each day?

Tags: database, database-design

I am building a scheduling system, and I have a table called `routes`. This would represent a route on a particular day, with the possibility for multiple routes per day. I'm wondering if it is a bad idea to automatically create this field each day, or 30 days out, or something like that; or, is it better to only create the `route` entry if I need it (I could create route entries only if there are going to be multiple routes each day, and limit the fields that are entered into the DB).

I know this questions could be considered opinion based, but I'm looking for a concrete answer about what you might call the best practice in this situation.

UPDATE:

The reason I'm thinking of adding this table is because I need to have the ability to display the available routes to a user when an admin adds a new route. I'm not sure how to do this without creating a new table which would "define" the route, and if a new route is added to a particular day, it could then be displayed on the front-end of the web app.

I don't know that I would need to refer to the routes in the past, I would need to reference the routes in the future.

Comment: If you can post the structure of the scheduling system and routes table, we can probably give you a better answer. As it is right now, as long as you have proper indexing and partitioning, depending on how big you expect the table to get and how quickly, this is not necessarily a bad thing. But the real question might be less about whether this is generally a good or bad thing, and more about whether your table structure is the best it can be for this scenario.

Comment: What is the "cost" of creating the route? If cheap then generate, if not, consider something else. What about history? Do you need to refer to routes used in the past? Too many unknown parameters here to give a good answer.

Comment: Thanks @Teeg. I'll see about posting the structure so everyone can have some better context.

Comment: @NealB I added some more info, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the context, which this is lacking. I'm guessing since 'route' exists, you're doing logistic based databases. It's really up to you, but keep in mind that extra rows  take up space. If you follow this option, you should keep your database in check.

Try to keep updating records as much as possible, and use a specific ID for the code fetching the request to follow. That way, you can keep *updating* your code instead of creating rows.